# Updating Tableview javaFX row by row

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I am facing problem in updating values in my table view.

I have a for loop which updates all my rows values. I am using StringProperty as my model class field types. When I update a single row it works fine. But my requirement is I need to stop for 1000 millisec in each row after updation. I tried using Thread.sleep(1000) in my for loop which is not helping :(

Comment: Can you post some code as to what you have tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to manipulate your Thread, it will be too complicate.

Simply use a TimeLine like this :

```
 timer = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            //Pause your timer in order to update your row
            timer.pause();

            //Do your update (increment your rowIndex inside)
            updateRowMethod(rowIndex);

            //Then launch the Timer and exit
            timer.play();
        }
    }));
```

I use the pause method because your said you wanted to wait 1000 milliseconds after the edition of a line. If you just want to edit a line every second, skip the pause/play part.